# Modem TS-9000 ADSL - Opened ports, but they're not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

So I have a `Telsec TS-9000 modem`, and I'm testing an old computer, using `Windows XP SP3`, firewall disabled, antivirus disabled, not behind a router, the modem's `DMZ` is disabled, I forward the `port 8080`, tried other ports too, but whenever I test them on online PING services, like this one ttp://ping.eu/port-chk/, it tells me the ports are closed. Have already restarted the modem. And the IP being used for opening ports is 192.168.1.3, any other than that, my IP is dynamic, I don't know how to say that, perhaps one it's local IP and the other one is my ISP IP.
I really need to open those ports. Also, when I go to firewall settings and hit the option `Filter IP/Port`, the first two options

```
Output Default Action: Allow
Entry Standard Action: Deny
```

Are greyed out.

Comment: Do you have anything listening on port 8080?

Comment: You are likely behind an Enterprise Grade NAT router, which makes incoming traffic impossible. What is the WAN or public IP address your router/modem is getting, not what whatsmyip.com shows? If it is in private space (10.x.x.x, 172.16-31.x.x, or 192.168.x.x) than you will not be able to access the device regardless of the public IP seen to others because of your ISP's routing.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get most things you said. I'm actually in a private property, pc directly connected to modem through Ethernet cable, using 192.168.xx

Comment: I have direct access to the modem, btw